# Function returns None after recursion

Tags: python, function, recursion

I have written a function to determine the height of a display, given a width and a format. The function operates recursively, if it cannot find a match for the given width and format while trying out a row of height values. The function works, if it finds a match before going into the recursion, but after that it always returns none and not the matching value pair. I am very confused as to why that is. Am I missing some principle here?

```
def getDisplayDimensions(width,FormatX,FormatY):
    Format = float(FormatX)/FormatY
    if FormatX < FormatY:
        return "illegal format."
    for height in range(1,int(width)+1):
        if float(width)/height == float(Format):
            return width,height
            break
        elif height == width:
            getDisplayDimensions(float(width)-1,FormatX,FormatY)

# example call:
print getDisplayDimensions(801,16,9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually returning the recursive call result:

```
elif height == width:
    getDisplayDimensions(float(width)-1,FormatX,FormatY)
```

Add `return` there:

```
elif height == width:
    return getDisplayDimensions(float(width)-1,FormatX,FormatY)
```

Without the `return` the outer call just ends and returns the default `None` instead.

Demo:

```
>>> def getDisplayDimensions(width,FormatX,FormatY):
...     Format = float(FormatX)/FormatY
...     if FormatX < FormatY:
...         return "illegal format."
...     for height in range(1,int(width)+1):
...         if float(width)/height == float(Format):
...             return width,height
...             break
...         elif height == width:
...             return getDisplayDimensions(float(width)-1,FormatX,FormatY)
... 
>>> print getDisplayDimensions(801,16,9)
(800.0, 450)
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. Then there is indeed a fundamental lack of understanding for me here... Because, I don't understand, why the call needs the return statement, if the return is within the function that is being called.

Comment: @user3578468: imagine calling a *different function* at that point; say you called `set([float(width)-1,FormatX,FormatY])` there instead. What do you think would happen then if you missed out the `return`? Calling a recursive function is no different here, you still need to return the result.